# RavenDB saves my "default" value before I even call Store()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I have this Model called Person with the obvious properties and a simple `int[]` array for `CoverPersons` in the Model.

The strange thing happens when I load the view in the controller. I do a Session.Query for the Person and check if the `CoverPersons == null` - So just for my page not to throw `null exceptions` on iterations I do a simple `CoverPersons = new int[] { -1 }`

I don't call `Store` anywhere, I was just getting from RavenDB but in the RavenDB Silverlight manager it saved the value `-1` into the CoverPersons array? For DB purposes that IS going to break things later since I don't have Person with ID= -1, if I ever needed to load that somewhere else and it was a new document.

So I turned the problem around and if the entity is null I leave it null and on the view I do a check if its null or not. I see RavenDB just puts the value `null` into the document now.

I am pretty NEW to RavenDB and I don't understand why its doing that. If thats a clever way to define a "default" safe value in Raven world, that is pretty cool.. but **is that a feature or a bug?**

Comment: By default, Raven will track changes on queried documents so you don't *have* to call `Store`. When you call `SaveChanges` it'll save any changes it detected. You can [override this default](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-customize-query#notracking), though. Personally, I use either `ICollection<T>` or some other list type and then initialize a default value in the ctor of my objects. This prevents any null reference issues and results in an empty array always being saved by default.

Comment: I think that is more of an answer. I did not realise that I was using my models in the entity framework kind of way. This is pretty awesome.

Comment: It's a mind-shift, there are more things like this when switching from EF to Raven (such as migrating `FirstOrDefault`s to `Load`s).

Comment: Yea that sounds like something I wondered how to do. Its all good, doing some small project to learn the ropes and its pretty awesome. Still need to get round to relationships... but I kind of know thats not the point of RavenDB so avoiding it as much as possible too see how far I get. Working pretty well though. Thanks.